# React application not running due to Content Security Policy

Tags: reactjs, heroku, content-security-policy

I have a build a React application and deployed it on Heroku. When I try to load my home page "/" I get no errors and the page loads perfectly. But when I try to navigate to a different page "/RegistrationList" I get the Content Security Policy errors:[image]

I have already searched for a solution online and found that I need to specify a Meta tag in the index.html file inside the public folder of my application. So now this file looks as follows:

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
      content="default-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
    />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Titillium+Web:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,400&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
...
```

But at this point I still keep on getting the errors. The strange thing is that the main page ("/") loads perfectly and the second page gives these errors.

Answer (score 0):

Your current CSP within the index.html is useless under a security point of view (you are allowing everything, so this is equivalent as not defining a CSP).

CSP can be defined either in your front-end (index.html) and back-end, and when there is a mismatch, you find all kinds of errors. If you try to remove the CSP meta tag from your index.html and you still get the error, it means the problem is in the server side.

In case of Apache server, this is located in file '*htaccess*'. As for Heroku, I don't know exactly where it is. Perhaps this can work:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/57288001/10802411